# Process Javascript Array of Arrays with Recursion

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm making a real-time chat app that allows you to reply to other people. The data is stored where each new message has an array to store replies to it, so an array may look like

```
FIRST MESSAGE
---REPLY TO FIRST MESSAGE
   ---REPLY TO SUB MESSAGE
---REPLY TO FIRST MESSAGE
   ---REPLY TO SUB MESSAGE
   ---REPLY TO SUB MESSAGE
```

I'm currently using the following code:

```
function process (obj, func) {
    func(obj);
    if (obj.child) {
        obj.child.forEach(function (child) {
            process(child, func);
        });
    }
}
```

And I call it with (*data* is the array of all messages):

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            process(data[i]['replies'], function (obj) {
            });
}
```

This only seems to get the first reply to each message, and just skips the rest. Any ideas for a recursive function that would prevent that? I'm really stuck here. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind! I got it. I needed to call another loop inside of the process function, like:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    process(data[i]['replies'], function (obj) {
        for (c = 0; c < obj.length; c++) {
        }
    });
}
```